# Syntax error with jquery selecting table row with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to pull the data out from a table row so that it can be updated, but I am really confused as to why it is not happening. Below is a snippet of generated HTML. The record ID is held in the first data element as the value of the attribute "name". In the sample below it is 2.

```
<tr title="Grp2">
  <td title="Select box"><input name="2" type="CHECKBOX"></td>
  <td title="ID">Dom</td>
  <td title="Description">Domestic</td>
  <td title="Archive">No</td>
<tr>
```

This has worked successfully to identify the appropriate records for deletion. I am now trying to extend on that, and get the values of the "ID" and "Description" elements as part of an update function, but keep getting this error in Firefox when trying to run the code.

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr["title"="Grp14"]
```

The js is:

```
function show_update_form() {
     lvl_prefix = $("#lvl_prefix").val() ;
     id = $("#grp_table_id").val() ;

     var grp_list = new Array();
     var list = "" ;    // list of category groups to be deleted
     var target = "" ;
     var cnt = 0 ;
     var confirm_list = "" ;
     var msg = "" ;
     var sel_ID = "" ;
     var sel_Desc = "" ;
     var fld_ID = "" ;
     var fld_Desc = "" ;

// create json list of groups to update
    list = '{"groups": [' ;
    target = id + " input:checked";
    cnt = 0 ;
    $(target).each(function(index){
        list += '{"id":' + $(this).attr("name") + '},' ;
        grp_list.push($(this).attr("name")) ;           // get list so can confirm delete
        cnt++ ;

        sel_ID   = 'tr["title"="Grp' + grp_list[cnt - 1] + '"] ' ;      // get current values
        sel_Desc = 'tr["title"="Grp' + grp_list[cnt - 1] + '"] ' ;
        fld_ID = $('tr["title"="Grp2"] ').filter('td["title"="ID"]').text() ;
//      fld_Desc = $(sel_Desc).filter('td["title"="Description"]').text() ;

        dlg_grp_update.dialog("open");      // show form and populate with current values



    }) ;
    list = list.substr(0, (list.length -1)) + ']}' ;    // remove last comma and add closing brackets

    if (cnt == 0) {     // ensure there is something to update
        alert( "Please select the Group you wish to update.") ;
        return ;
    }

}   // function show_update_form
```

Firefox has a hernia at the line:

```
fld_ID = $('tr["title"="Grp2"] ').filter('td["title"="ID"]').text() ;
```

You can see form the lines around it that the plan is to generate this line from variables, but I have tried to simplify it as much as possible and have now hardcoded it just to see if there were typos in the generation process.

This has the feel of something that is simple and obvious, but you can't see the wood for all the trees!

Ideas? What is the right syntax to select a table row with a specific attribute?

thanks,
Darryl

Comment: Try just `tr[title="Grp2"]` http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Try using "ID" or "data-" attributes or class names instead of the "title" attribute and use it like `$("tr#gid2").find("TD.username").text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove *double quotes* from title in the expression.

```
fld_ID = $('tr[title="Grp2"] td[title="ID"]').text() ;
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3y0t8y90/

Comment: Already have. I moved to the "filter" version to try and isolate the error. When I used the extended form, the whole string was listed as the syntax error anthise filter version was an attempt to reduce the area of uncertainty.

Comment: Vijay is right, you need to remove the double quotes from the `title` to make the selector work.

Comment: Vijay, sorry - missed the removal of double quotes bit. That is what is needed and this is the correct answer.

Comment: I realise what happened - getting confused with json syntax that I had been working on. In the strict json syntax both the name and value should be quoted, but JS relaxes the rules on quoting the name. This caused problems when handing the json over to php, so I learnt to quote everything. Unfortunately I started doing it for jquery where it was illegal to do so. Why can't we have uniform syntax!!!!!

Comment: Json is different than jQuery selector conventions :)

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery `filter()` is not being used properly.

`filter` means take a set of elements and filter out the ones with the specified selector.

`find` is used to find elements WITHIN the set of elements using the specified selector.

So try this:

```
fld_ID = $('tr[title="Grp2"] ').find('td[title="ID"]').text();
```

As an aside, using a `title` is probably not the best way to do this. Adding an ID to the `tr` would be better:

- The user won't see a title tooltip while hovering over the row
- The javascript id selector is much faster than an attribute selector, so if you are processing a lot of rows, using an id will be faster overall.

---

Vijay is correct, the double quotes around the `title` are causing the problem with the selector. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I will bear the filter vs find comment in mind when I get the syntax working. Re title, I do want the tootips showing in this case.

Comment: @Mottie: Thanks for mentioning....Your answers adds the good part of choosing the right method b/w filter & find :)